# Periodically update data state

Tags: ember.js

I'm creating a browser game that doesn't connect to a server.  It stores all the state in Ember Data using the fixture adapter.  One part of the game is a user a can click a button and "go on a mission".  The mission has a duration.  I would like to update the state of the game when the mission duration has elapsed.

I was going about this by periodically updating the mission controller and checking the time until the mission was over and then updating the state with the results.  However I noticed that when I navigated to a different route it would destroy the controller.  With the controller destroyed I had nothing to update the mission periodically.  So even though the duration elapsed it didn't update the state of the game.

I don't understand why the controller is being destroyed?  This may be because the controller is an item-controller?  This is my first ember app so I may have set up something incorrectly.

Also if there is a better way to go about this I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `itemController`s are destroyed, when the route is left:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.route('other');
});

App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  _setup: function () {
    alert('_setup IndexController')
  }.on('init'),
  
  itemController: 'item'
});

App.OtherController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  _setup: function () {
    alert('_setup OtherController')
  }.on('init')
});

App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    _setup: function () {
      alert('_setup ItemController')
  }.on('init'),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.7.0/ember.js"></script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    
    {{#link-to 'other'}}Other{{/link-to}}
  </script>

  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="other">
    {{#link-to 'index'}}Back{{/link-to}}
  </script>
```

In this case, I'd say create a service object attached to your application controller, that is scheduling updates with [`Ember.run.later()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later).

Also, please note that the FixtureAdapter is not able to actually *store* data.

Comment: Thanks!  I am using Ember.run.later() to do updates, but the problem is that I am calling a function in the item controller, which then gives me this error: Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote in the beginning of my answer... You could consider a property on e.g. the ApplicationController that is updated via Ember.run.later every second, and make the game state a computed property depending on this...